# Отправка файлов на e-mail

Tags: email, c++, visual-c++

Как на Visual C++ отправить файл на электронную почту?

Comment: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/qna/inet/email.xml

Answer (score 3):

У вас есть варианты:

- писать простейший SMTP клиент, который будет отправлять почту через сокеты ([пример](http://web.archive.org/web/20090108031706/http://www.vijaymukhi.com/vmis/smtpprg.htm)),
- использовать сторонний класс, библиотеку и тд. ([пример](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/zsmtp.aspx)).